# based on my domain names i need to separate the view folder

Tags: laravel-5

based on my domain names i need to separate the view folder,so i have created  ModifyViewFolder class file in middleware and also registered in kernel.php but its not working properly dont know how to check working or not.and also please verify my kernel.php file in this i dont know registered right or not.

file path: 'View'=> \App\Http\Middleware\ModifyViewFolder::class

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class ModifyViewFolder
{

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      $finder = new FileViewFinder(app()['files'], [
        app_path('../resources/views/' . $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST')),
        app_path('../resources/views/'),

      ]);
      View::setFinder($finder);

      return $next($request);
  }

}
```

kernel.php: App\Http\kernel.php

protected $routeMiddleware = [

```
    'View'=> \App\Http\Middleware\ModifyViewFolder::class,
     ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this below . Please assign the path in $middleware.

```
protected $middleware = [
 \App\Http\Middleware\ModifyViewFolder::class,    
];
```